# Alowing Firebase Analytics domain names without allowing other Google services

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an app which is meant to be used inside an internal network behind firewall. There is a requirement to enable Firebase Analytics to this app, and the network admin need to allow the Firebase endpoints without allowing all the Google Services. So far I came to know that I need to allow `*.firebase.com` and `*.firebaseio.com` in the firewall.

But the challenge here is, will other Google sites be allowed through the firewall by allowing those domains? If so, what are the sites? I am posting this question since StackOverflow was mentioned as one of the support channel in the official support page.

Answer (score 4):

If you turn on debug mode or intercept the traffic, you will see traffic to https://app-measurement.com:

```html
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
```