# Firebase analytics network connections (url, port, ip addresses)?

Tags: firebase, networking, firewall, firebase-analytics, private-network

Our company will setup mobile devices which use private mobile network (special sim card which blacklist all urls and allow for only specific urls).

(Our company has a firewall and it is preventing our enterprise mobile app from sending analytic events to Firebase via the SDK.)

We have a scenario to use Firebase-analytic to log user events. So far I am trying to find what are the urls or IP addresses which device will request to firebase-analytics when logging but I could not find any network information.

All network information for firebase which I could get is only network for FCM (port 5228-5230). However, I couldn't find any information about firebase-analytics.

In conclusion, **what are urls/ip addresses and ports which should I need to open for using firebase-analytics** in this private network?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, I understand that firebase will connect to the to Google's ASN of 15169 (https://ipinfo.io/AS15169) via port 443 (HTTPS) but my company does not allow to config firewall for 485 rules (refer to 485 subnets in AS15169).

I tried to troubleshoot by enable debug log on android but does not see any URL like it was mentioned in [Alowing Firebase Analytics domain names without allowing other Google services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105032/alowing-firebase-analytics-domain-names-without-allowing-other-google-services)

Thank for the answer in this topic, right now we found that we should whitelist an url for firebase analytics as https://app-measurement.com